# hover to show content of a name anchor in a popup instead of click to go to the content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a long html, the contents have references for other text.

For example:

```
What is your <a href="#A8">favorite</a> day?
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="A1">Monday</div>
<div id="A2">Tuesday</div>
<div id="A3">Wednesday</div>
<div id="A4">Thursday</div>
<div id="A5">Friday</div>
<div id="A6">Saturday</div>
<div id="A7">Subday</div>
<div id="A8">It's a good day.</div>
```

I hope to have a function to hover on an anchor tag to show the content in a popup or dialog of the anchor name instead of clicking to go to the content. No go back and forth.

If hovering on `#A8`, it will show the content of `A8`, that's "It's a good day. "

Comment: onclick=alert(document.getElementById("AB").innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options.

1. Use lightbox/thickbox/jquery to display the content in the section `A8` in an overlay.
2. Replace `<a href="#A8">favorite</a>` with `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openPopup('#A8')">favorite</a>`. In the function openPopup, grab the contents of the section `A8` and show it in a popup(using window.open).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The quickies for begin that comes to my mind:

```
<div class="day" id="A1">Monday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for Monday</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A2">Tuesday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for Tuesday</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A3">Wednesday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for Wedsday</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A4">Thursday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for Thursday</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A5">Friday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for ...</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A6">Saturday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for ...</div></div>
<div class="day" id="A7">Subday<div class="content">your content that will show up on hover for ...</div></div>
```

in the CSS add:

```
.day .content{
display:none;
}
.day:hover .content{
display:block;
}
```

Latter you may try a bunch of effects that JQuery offers.

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this

What is your <a href="#" onclick=GoodDay();>favorite</a> day?
<div></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="A1">Monday</div>
<div id="A2">Tuesday</div>
<div id="A3">Wednesday</div>
<div id="A4">Thursday</div>
<div id="A5">Friday</div>
<div id="A6">Saturday</div>
<div id="A7">Subday</div>

<script>
function GoodDay(){  $(this).next('div').text("It's a good day.");}
<script>
```